# Exact value of $0<\wp^{-1}(2^{-{2/3}})<2$ with $\wp$ the Weierstrass elliptic function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-functions

I am investigating solutions to the differential equation
$$\ddot{y}(t)=6y(t)^2,\dot{y}(0), y(0)=y_0>0.\tag{1}\label{1} $$
Let $\wp(t)$ be the Weierstrass elliptic function with elliptic invariants $g_2=0, g_3=1$, *i.e.*  the equianharmonic case. I have found that the solution to equation $(\ref{1})$ is given by
$$y(t)=2^{2/3}y_0\wp\left(2^{1/3}\sqrt{y_0}t+\lambda_0\right),$$
where $\lambda_0$ is such that, letting $t=0$,
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\wp(\lambda_0)=2^{-2/3},\\
\wp'(\lambda_0)=0.$$
I am interested in what is the exact value (if there is one) of $\lambda_0$, given that $0<\lambda_0<2$. I restrict the domain because $\wp$ is a periodic function. Numerically, by *Mathematica*, I have found that $\lambda_0\sim 1.52995$. The value seems to numerically agree with the half period of the equianharmonic $\wp$ function: $\omega_2= \Gamma^3(1/3)/4\pi$. I would be happy to see a proof of this.

Comment: $y=0$ are the points of order 2 on the elliptic curve.

Comment: Since the elliptic curve has CM, $\omega_2$ is called an elliptic integral singular value. It can indeed be computed in terms of the gamma function using results of Legendre: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html

Comment: $\wp'(\lambda_0)=0$ means that $\lambda_0$ is the half-period. This proves your observation.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Do you have a good reference for this? Your train of logic isn't clear to me.

Comment: On elliptic functions, any book, for example Akhiezer, Elements of the theory of elliptic functions, good general Complex Variable textbooks also contain this material, for example Ahlfors. For a list of formulas Abramowitz Stegun handbook is sufficient for most purposes.